# Xamarin Forms UWP - Pdfjs viewer source file

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, uwp, pdf.js

Inside the WebView I use PdfJs viewer ([github link](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)) to show Pdf document.

Is it possible to set a source file **not from Assets folder**?? For example:

```
var uriString = "ms-appx-web:///Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=ms-appdata:///local/Test/test.pdf";

Control.Navigate(new Uri(uriString));
```

Expected result: viewer grabs file located in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder (inside it i created Test folder and a file in it) and shows it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: According to the [document](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/): **Note: the worker is not enabled for file:// urls, so use a server.** I'm afraid we can't set a source file located in app's local folder.

Comment: did you ever find a solution or this?